# Hide or remove spans from a block of pregenerated html

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to remove all the spans or event the element styling from them?

They are created by VBulletin so I cant manually do it

```
<div class="thanklist">
        <a href="member.php?u=1394" rel="nofollow"><span style="color: #F3484E; font-weight:bold;">mynameisdonald</span></a>
        <a href="member.php?u=1394" rel="nofollow"><span style="color: #F3484E; font-weight:bold;">mynameisdonald</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you stuck?

Comment: Just hoping someone could show my some jquery that'll remove this span or remove the styling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `removeAttr()` method, try the following:

```
$('.thanklist span').removeAttr('style');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SyZAL/)

Or if you want to remove them the spans you can use `remove()` method:

```
$('.thanklist span').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SyZAL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
​$('.thanklist span').each(function(i, el){
    $(this).parent().html($(this).html());
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a css class:

```
span {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: That would also remove the text inside the span, I think he just wants to remove the styling.